# Reference request: a lemma that exterior products of an injective map of free modules are injective.

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1\in R$. Let $M,N$ be free $R$-modules. Let $\phi:M\to N$ be an injective map. Then for any $k\in\mathbb N$, the exterior product
\begin{equation}
    \wedge^k\varphi:\wedge^kM\to \wedge^kN
\end{equation}
is also injective. I can find a statement and proof in [Theorem 5.10](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/extmod.pdf). However, I want to know if there are published books or papers that I can cite for the result.

Comment: I don't know of any, but I'm also not sure you'd need to cite something for this. It's a "well-known" result that follows from the fact that free modules are flat.

Comment: In Bourbaki's Algebra you can find a proof for projective modules